# How to index MySql table with over a million records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code works perfect on a small table, but I have a table that has 1.8 million records, so my search time is about 12 seconds.  I created a b-tree index on my table via Phpmyadmin on client_id and customername and no change in speed.  My table contains 116 columns. Do I need to break up my table into multiple tables and use the join command? Ive seen the join command, but have never used it before  If so can someone give a quick example

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(:currentlat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(:currentlon) ) 
+ sin( radians(:currentlat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )   AS distance FROM $live_table

WHERE  (companyname like :name  )

AND

is_active != :active_switch

HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id desc LIMIT $start, $limit");

$stmt->bindValue(':name' , "%$name%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':currentlat' , "$currentlat", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':currentlon' , "$currentlon", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':mydistance' , "$mydistance", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindValue(':active_switch' , "$active_switch", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: actually I have about 15 fields that will have a lot of searches that I need to index somehow.  the above is the most simple I can make it for the question above.   I  have fields such as address, city, state ect...

Comment: Please read this set of suggestions about SQL questions, especially the part on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: does "3959" change per query?

Comment: No, 3959 is a constant

Comment: Exactly. 3959 is the number of miles in one radian (57.3958 degrees) of latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important reason your query is slow is the `HAVING DISTANCE < :mydistance` clause. That compels your MySQL server to compute the distance to every row, and then to filter them, and probably causes a full table scan of your megarow table.

You probably should use a bounding-box computation in your WHERE clause. The idea is to exclude rows from your table that lie too far south, north, east, or west to fall within your `:mydistance` range. That's a good idea because your query can then use an index on the `lat` column to rule out lots of rows.  It will look something like this:

```
...
WHERE  (companyname like :name  )
AND
is_active != :active_switch
AND lat  BETWEEN :currentlat - (:mydistance / 69.0 )
             AND :currentlat + (:mydistance / 69.0 )
AND long BETWEEN :currentlong - (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
             AND :currentlong + (:mydistance / (111.045 * COS(RADIANS(latpoint))))
HAVING distance < :mydistance ORDER BY client_id desc LIMIT $start, $limit
```

A writeup of this bounding box search is [here](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/). The magic number `69.0` comes from the fact that there are approximately 69 miles in every degree of latitude. `3959` is the number of miles in one radian (57.3958 degrees) of latitude.

The way you have written this query, though, makes it hard to use indexes to accelerate it. [It's not sargable as written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). If you can recast your criteria as

```
 WHERE companyname = :name
   AND is_active = :inactive_switch
   AND lat BETWEEN ...
   AND long BETWEEN ...
```

then a compound index on `(companyname, is_active, lat)` will produce a miraculous improvement in query performance. The query planner can random-access the index to the appropriate starting value of `lat`, then scan it sequentially to the last relevant value.

Please notice that creating lots of single column indexes is generally harmful to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` performance, and is generally useless to help make `SELECT` queries faster.

Please also notice that `SELECT *` is harmful to query performance, especially in tables with many columns and with the `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` pattern. Why? MySQL has to sort a whole mess of long rows, just to discard all but a few of them. You're much better off listing the columns you actually need in your `SELECT` statement.

116 columns is a very large -- some would say pathologically large -- number of columns to have in one table, especially a megarow table.  It's hard to make recommendations for restructuring your data without knowing more about it. You may want to investigate the topic called database normalization.

Comment: Thank you, Awsome explanation and is kind of what I thought.  I need to redesign my tables to be more effcient.  This was the first table I ever designed, so its time to educate myself on good table structure.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that your query take a long time is using Sin, Cos, ACos functions in your query.

As you know:

- Product operation is about 32 times slower than a sum operation.
- Sin, Cos, ACos is about 50 times slower than product operation, i.e. about 1500 times slower than sum operation.

As you see these calculations are very time-consuming. especially when you repeat these calculations for millions of rows.

What you need is:

- Define tables for Sin, Cos & ACos function results with the proper precision you want.
- Then define some UDFs for these functions to calculate result of these function based on the nearest result from your tables.
- Use these UDFs instead of built-in functions for Sin, Cos, ACos.

Comment: If you're using an intel 286 without a floating point unit, yeah, make some cosine lookup tables. But you probably are using a modern machine, and the floating point unit consumes a few hundred nanoseconds on each distance computation.  The problem here is not the cost of the distance computation, it's the fact that the questioner's query, as written, must repeat that computation for every row of the megarow table. The cost is not the computation, it's the IO to scan the whole table. Your suggestion to build a UDF is both unnecessary and insufficient to solve the problem, with respect.